# How could I add the FLIP Fluids obstacle component to multiple objects at once?

Tags: objects, add-on, physics, fluid-simulation

I'm creating a simulation involving a cell-fractured object. There are 600+ objects in my scene that have to be FLIP Fluid obstacles, is it possible to add the component to each object automatically? There's a similar feature to this for copying Rigidbody settings.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! I selected all of the fractures, clicked on the sidebar, and hit the Add/Remove Obstacle button.

[image: Sidebar with Add/Remove buttons]